# Stylus delay in Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I am experiencing a problem with the Grease Pencil where there will be a delay between my stylus stroke and the stroke that is actually drawn in Blender. I would start to draw something with the Grease Pencil, but the stroke doesn't actually start until a little past my starting point. This is really annoying especially when trying to draw connecting lines because a small gap will be present between the two lines where the delay occurred.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you for your help!

Specs:

- Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 370
- Blender 2.79b (also occurred with 2.8 Alpha)
- Core i5
- Intel Graphics 620

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120009/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This was exactly my question, but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. Thanks though!

Comment: I assume you are using Windows? It's not working for me either. I'm not even sure whether it's a time delay or some fixed pixel distance (some drag threshold). Using Blender on Linux might be a workaround (works for me).

Comment: I've resorted to a similar solution. Hopefully Blender fixes this soon. Is there a workaround with using a Wacom Tablet?

Comment: It appears to have been fixed (works for me): https://developer.blender.org/T55589

Comment: Blender 2.80 beta seemed to also improve it a bit more too. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem appears to have been solved in Blender 2.81a**. For people who come across this, update your Blender to 2.81a. If this doesn't work, try the solution mentioned in the comments.