# Mouse is painting, stylus is erasing

Tags: texture-painting

I am using Blender 2.91 and a Huion stylus. I set up a simple mesh, with a texture material, and switched to texture paint mode, using the default brush. Everything is working great when I use the mouse, but **when I use the stylus it's behaving like an eraser** and it's clearing whatever I touch to alpha 0. See video below.

[image: Mouse is painting, stylus is erasing]

Larger image. Left screenshot is what I get after left-clicking with the mouse and dragging; right screenshot is stylus-down and dragging.

[image: Mouse is painting, stylus is erasing]

What's going on?

**Some ideas**

Could it be a virtual/button/mapping issue of some sort? Under which condition the same thing would happen when using the mouse? Maybe if a modifier key is pressed?

Comment: It's pretty hard to make out what's going on from such a small gif. Could you [edit] in a couple screenshots in instead? Win + Shft + S is a good way to do screenshots on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to use Win + Shft + S a lot from now on!

Answer (score 2):

Even though the poster was having a different problem, one of the answers to another question [Painting problem when using pen in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120009/painting-problem-when-using-pen-in-blender/142938#142938) seems to do the trick for me. If I change the `Preferences > Input > Tablet > Tablet API` to `Windows Ink` then the stylus paints with the selected color.

I have no clue why this is happening though; I will accept any answer that sheds some more light on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is my contribution. Maybe it was something simple. Make sure you haven't pressed the stylus button that switches to eraser mode. It happened to me once and I wasted a few minutes trying to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

On default the top button is "Pen/Eraser". However I had changed (customised) the top button to be "right click" and I was at a loss what to do as every time I used the pen it just erased.

[image]

I solved it by switching it back to the default *Pen/Eraser* clicked it once, checked that the pen painted then switched it back to "right click" as I use it for navigation.  Then from then on it works as a pen/brush